# I need download instructions for this set, but I don’t know the number, light green and black pieces

Tags: set-identification, instructions

[image]

I need to download instructions for this set, but I don’t know the set number.

Answer (score 6):

This bag is from [70736-1: Attack of the Morro Dragon](https://brickset.com/sets/70736-1/Attack-of-the-Morro-Dragon)

Based on:

- [6116600: Ninja Sword](https://brickset.com/parts/6116600/ninja-sword)
- [6109561: Blade 10M W/Ø3.2](https://brickset.com/parts/6109561/blade-10m-w-%C3%B83-2)
- [6039194: Stone 1X2X1 1/3 W. 2 Plates 2X2](https://brickset.com/parts/6039194/stone-1x2x1-1-3-w-2-plates-2x2)

and a double check with the instructions.